# Solution for iPhone leaving home

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I searching for a solution to tell a Linux-application that the iPhone left the house and come back again. (in Swift ;-) )

I testing some ways, but nothing works in the right way. 
When i using WLAN-connection lost, so the Linux think that i'm away when my iPhone goes to standby, because iOS shutdown the WLAN in Background.
When i using background location the time between the location updates is too long.

Can i use the Homekit to do something like that? Or is there anyone who did something like this?

Comment: you want it to be from iphone side or server side?

Comment: maybe you can try and use a zeroconf protocol, apple has bonjour which works pretty good, but i don't know what version on linux do you use and if its supported

Comment: from witch side does not matter. important is only, that i dont want to use another iphone-App. I want to realize that in my own app, or only on Linux.

Comment: bonjour sounds good. Do you have any instructions to realize that?

Answer (score 3):

The SetSDK will allow you to setup an in-app notification for when a user arrives to or departs from home, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK. The SDK learns where home is and then starts to fire the notifications off. So for departing home, you would do,

```
SetSDK.instance.onDeparture(from: .home) { 
    /* do your Swift things here */
}
```

In that example, you rely on the SetSDK to learn where home is first. If you already know a location where you want to get departure alerts, the easiest right now is to do,

```
SetSDK.instance.onDeparture(from: .any) { departedPlace in
    /* Compare the departed location with the one of interest */
    if departedPlace.location.distance(from: knownLocation) < 50 {
      /* do your things here */
    }
}
```